# Use controller action to retrieve data from one model and save data to another model - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`CartItem` Controller and `CartItem` model handle adding items to `CartItems` table. Cart view is rendered by calling `CartItem` model and controller. When clicking ‘Checkout’ I would like to transfer all items saved for a given card in the `CartItem` table to the `OrderItem` table.

When clicking ‘Checkout’ on the cart view page the following things should happen:
Call Orders controller from `Cart view`

```
<%= button_to "Checkout", controller: 'orders', action: 'create' %>
```

Orders Controller

```
def create
  @order = Order.new
  if logged_in?
    @order[:user_id] = current_user.id     #This works
  end  

  #Need help: call Order_Items_Controller create action

  if @order.save
    flash[:success] = "Order created"
  else  
    flash[:danger] = "Failed"
  end
  redirect_to checkout_address_path
end
```

OrderItems Controller

```
def create
  #retrieve all records from Cart_Items where cart_id matches cookies[:cart_id]
  @order_item = @order.order_items.build!(CartItem.where(:cart_id => cookies[:cart_id]))

  #Need help: add order_id for current order to each record 
  #Need help: save the cart_items to the order_items table and handle exceptions  
end
```

Orders Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
end
```

OrderItems Model

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  validates :order_id, presence: true
end
```

Why do I want to do this? Once an order is successfully processed the corresponding CartItems data will be deleted, so that the card is empty. OrderItems stores the data for completed orders, so that shoppers can view order history online.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about the setup of your models/data structure?

Specifically, duplicating data in one model to another is highly inefficient. You'll be MUCH better using a `foreign_key` to link your `Order` model to your cart:

```
#app/models/cart.rb
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
   #stores cart items for processing
   belongs_to :order
   has_many   :cart_items
end 

#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   #stores final values (IE delivery service id, cart id, payment id etc)
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :delivery
   belongs_to :payment
   has_one    :cart
end
```

This way, you'll be able to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/carts_controller.rb
class CartsController < ApplicationController
   def checkout
      @cart  = current_user.cart #-> or however you call it
      @order = @cart.order.new order_params
      if @order.save
         #-> remove cart from session etc etc
      end
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:delivery_id, :user_id, :payment_id)
   end
end
```

Obviously very high-level, but quite descriptive -- an `Order` becomes a glorified join model, allowing you to compile a "cart" with the relative quantities & items, whilst using the `Order` to manage the delivery and payments etc.

Comment: My intention for `CartItems` is to hold 14 days worth of uncompleted orders, while the `OrderItems` table would hold years worth of completed orders. By separating the tables like this the lighter `CartItems` table should perform very well in terms of response times. The less frequently called `OrderItems` table would hold the bulk of the data, but I'm open to suggestions, if this is not a good approach.

Comment: Duplicating records is typically bad practice; it would be better to store your cart items in a single table, which you may reassign to another table if necessary. In regards the efficiency of that setup, unless you're storing 100,000's of records, the impact of a query on a db isn't going to be major.

Comment: The duplication is temporary. Once a successful payment is collected the `CartItems` data will be deleted. Could you give me a pointer on how to copy the data to the `OrderItems` model?